# how to send notifications to clients that connect to the same tmux session?

Tags: ssh, tmux, notifications, notify-send

I have a python script running on a server (let's called box A) inside a tmux session. I ssh into box A from Box B and connect to this tmux session. My question is how do I send some kinds of notification / messages from my python script (running on box A) to my box B and trigger box B to make different sounds (depends on the notification) ?

I assume you can write something to a file on box B from the python script on box A and running a script on box B to monitor this file. I'm just wondering if there're any easy / builtin method in tmux to make these easier.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange.com ! Various solutions (askubuntu.com/questions/57035, unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34777, ...) exist which are platform/hw dependent. You could adapt them to your use case. They all involve sending instruction to a sound server on box B (e.g. pulse-audio if available) and allocating a socket to listen to a TCP port or socket on the remote side (which in yr case would be Box A.  In any case tmux has ***nothing*** to do at all with all that.  --- Please edit OP to include your distro and release if applicable and specific platform.

Comment: box A is linux (centos 7), B could be windows, osx, or linux. But it's disappointing that tmux can not trigger a script on client's computer.